# Multiple journals, same PKP, different domains (virtual hosts)

Tags: virtualhost, ojs

A single installation of OJS/PKP (Open Journal Systems/Public Knowledge Project) can host several online journals. Normally, they would be distinguished by path, e.g. as https://www.ojsdomain.org/index.php/journal1 https://www.ojsdomain.org/index.php/journal2 ...

But would it be possible to install OJS/PKP once, have it manage several journals, but access these through separate domains, e.g. as https://journal1.ojsdomain.org/index.php/journal1 , https://journal2.ojsdomain.org/index.php/journal2

(It is more a question about virtual hosting, perhaps, but motivated by optimizing the installation of OJS/PKP.)